# how to read data from hyperterminal and display as required

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperterminal

I had a some embedded circuit connected to my system for which it will send data to hyper-terminal
Now i want to read the data from hyper-terminal and use in my .net application

so please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might as well access the terminal via the serial interface directly.

You can refer this link:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/8b97df03-6e7f-4b85-8fbc-d208f82012bf

Hope its helpful.